# Error When Using MS Access StrConv Function

Tags: sql, combobox, ms-access-2013, delphi-10-seattle

### Introduction

I have a form with a `TComboBox` that I want to populate with a field from a table in my database using a query. I also want the values in the field displayed in **proper case**, which can be achieved using Access’ `StrConv` function. Here’s my code:

```
with dmCallNote.qryCompany, SQL do
begin
  Clear;
  Text := 'SELECT StrConv(A_Company, 3) FROM tblAccounts';
  Open;
  while not Eof do
  begin
    cmbCompany.Items.Add(dmCallNotes.qryCompany['A_Company']);
    Next;
  end;
end;
```

### The Problem

When compiling the line `cmdCompany.Items.Add …` I receive the error message:

“qryCompany: Field 'A_Company' not found.”

Why am I getting this error? When I run the query with a `TDBGrid` it executes successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:
`Text := 'SELECT StrConv(A_Company, 3) FROM tblAccounts';`

to this:
`Text := 'SELECT StrConv(A_Company, 3) AS A_Company FROM tblAccounts';`

Your field had no name/alias.